# Конфликт между аккордеоном и parallax js

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, css3, parallax

Используется аккордеон написанный на jquery, под ним находится секция с параллакс эффектом, при нажатии на аккордеон, он наезжает на секцию с параллаксом, вместо того, чтоб растянуть страницу вниз, как это и должно быть.. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой же проблемой и знает как решить?

пример: https://codepen.io/alexmillern/pen/oNgmOdX

```
<section class="competition">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="accordion">
            <dl>
           <dt class="accordion__title">Dt1</dt>
               <dd class="accordion__descr">Dd1</dd>

         </dl>
        </div>
</section>


<section class="insert" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="https://img5tv.cdnvideo.ru/webp/shared/files/201908/1_960015.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="insert__content">
            <h2 class="insert__title">Title</h2>
            <div class="insert__descr">Desciption</div>
</section>



$(".accordion dd").hide().prev().click(function() {
$(this).parents(".accordion").find("dd").not(this).slideUp().prev().removeClass("active");
$(this).next().not(":visible").slideDown().prev().addClass("active");});
```

Comment: добавьте пример кода, чтобы можно было ответить на Ваш вопрос, не тыкая пальцем в небо. Так уж принято. Не мучайте тех, кто старается Вам помочь. Чем больше деталей, тем лучше. В стандартном отношении аккордеон меняет размер секции, а не страницы в целом. То есть элементы за его пределами он не сдвигает и не перемещает. Скорее всего из-за этого и происходит наложение.

Comment: пример добавил.

Comment: дак у вас `overlay` вообще находится не в паралаксе

Comment: суть то не в этом, он двигает контент, который находится в паралаксе, а не его самого. если убрать overlay, будет аналогично все

Comment: @AlexRM потому что у `.parallax-mirror` инлайном прописано `position: fixed;`. Поэтому этот блок не двигается